# Unison preserve directory time

Tags: directory, timestamp, synchronization, unison

In the Unison (two way file syncing program) manual, when you set the `-times=true` preference, only the time stamps of the files are kept unchanged, not the directores:

From the Manual:

**times** *When this flag is set to true, file modification times (but not directory modtimes) are propagated.*

I wanted to see if there is any way the directory time could also be preserved during a sync?

Answer (score 3):

[This open issue](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/issues/172) says that it's not possible, and non-trivial to implement.

You could `unison` first, then `rsync -r --times --size-only --existing` afterwards to sync just the times on paths which already exist.

Answer (score 2):

After looking through the [Unison manual](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html), it appears that that answer to this question is *No*.